# Codeigniter getting values from mysql database and showing in html table

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, codeigniter

I want to know what is the correct procedure of getting the all rows of the mysql database and showing them in a html table. i know the view is used for the html, model used for the database insert, etc, and controller used between view and model.

An example of the model,view,controller, is fine. Trying to get something like, in a table.

```
Id  Firstname   Lastname
1   John    Doe
2   Mary    Moe
3   Julie   Dooley
```

Comment: The correct procedure is to research for yourself (google it out), there are too many approaches to this problem (I can think of 3 right now). You want code from SO users please do it for yourself and come back with a bit of code if you need help. See [guide](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/overview/mvc.html).

Comment: codeigniter provides clear documentation on http://ellislab.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a model to get the records
Lets assume your model name is mymodel

```
class Mymodel extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
    }
    function getInfos()
    {
        $this->db->select("*");//better select specific columns  
        $this->db->from('YOUR_TABLE_NAME');
        $result = $this->db->get()->result();
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Now your controller. Lets assume your controller name is mycontroller

```
class Mycontroller extends  CI_Controller
{
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('mymodel');
    }
    public function index()
    {


        $data['infos']=$this->mymodel->getInfos();
        $this->load->view("myview",$data);//lets assume your view name myview

    }

}
```

Now your view-myveiw.php

```
<table>
    <thead>
         <tr>
             <th>ID</th>
             <th>Firstname</th>
             <th>Lastname</th>
         </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
         <?php if((sizeof($infos))>0){
                foreach($infos as $info){
                ?>
                    <tr>
                       <td><?php echo $info->Id;?></td>
                       <td><?php echo $info->Firstname;?></td>
                       <td><?php echo $info->Lastname;?></td>
                     </tr>

                <?php
                }
          }else{ ?>
                <tr><td colspan='3'>Data Not Found</td></tr>
           <?php } ?>
     </tbody>


</table>
```

Hope this help you